# Probability and Statistics, Penicillin is grown in a broth whose sugar content must be carefully controlled.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Penicillin is grown in a broth whose sugar content must be carefully controlled. The optimum sugar concentration is 4.9 mg/mL. If the concentration exceeds 6.0 mg/mL, the fungus dies and the process must be shut down for the day. If the sugar concentration is batches of broth is normally distributed with mean 4.9 mg/mL and standard deviation 0.6 mg/mL, what is the probability that the probability that the process will shut down?

**I got an answer of 0.0336**

**What I am stuck on is the following question of what is the probabilty that the sugar content will be between 4.5 and 5.5 mg/mL?**

Comment: Aside from the fact that a random variable of sugar concentrations, here denoted $X$, cannot be normally distributed (*concentrations are always positive*), here is a hint at how to compute the probability that $X$ is between $4.5\,\frac{\mathrm{mg}}{\mathrm{ml}}$ and $5.5\,\frac{\mathrm{mg}}{\mathrm{ml}}$:
$$
P\left(4.5\,\frac{\mathrm{mg}}{\mathrm{ml}} < X \leq 5.5\,\frac{\mathrm{mg}}{\mathrm{ml}}\right) = P\left(X \leq 5.5\,\frac{\mathrm{mg}}{\mathrm{ml}}\right) - P\left(X \leq 4.5\,\frac{\mathrm{mg}}{\mathrm{ml}}\right).
$$

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Modelling nonnegative quantities by normal random variables is entirely standard, please do not mislead the OP. In the present case (mean 4.9, standard deviation 0.6), the probability that the corresponding normal random variable is negative is of the order of $10^{-16}$, which is negligible for every practical purpose.

Comment: @Did: I recommend to read an often-cited article of a guest speaker I invited last year to our institute's colloquium: http://bioscience.oxfordjournals.org/content/51/5/341.

Comment: OK, enough is enough: please stop invoking **completely unrelated** sources as if they were supporting the ludicrous claims you concocted by yourself. Next time you meet your guest speaker, just ask them if negative values **below 8 sigmas** are a problem for using normal distributions for modelling purposes. Their answer might enlighten you, since you are not listening to what people are explaining to you here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably for the first part you worked out $$p(X>6)=p(z>\frac{6-4.9}{0.6})=p(z>\frac{11}{6})=1-\Phi(1.833...)=0.03362$$

Likewise, for the second part you need $$p(4.5<X<5.5)=p(\frac{4.5-4.9}{0.6}<z<\frac{5.5-4.9}{0.6})=p(-\frac 23<z<1)=\Phi(1)+\Phi(\frac 23)-1$$
Which you can get from the tables.....

Comment: **(.8413)(1)+(.7257)(2/3)-1**  I got 0.3251, but its wrong

Comment: I am not sure whether or not the values are correct from the table.

Comment: I have 0.748 instead of 0.7257

Comment: That gave me 0.36396666, but two classmates got 0.5899, so I am not sure, and they are also not sure now, whether or not its 0.5899 or 0.3640

Comment: You have 0.8413+0.748-1=0.5893. Their answer could be from using a different value for $\Phi(\frac 23)$  such as $\Phi(0.67)$

Comment: You shouldn't be multiplying the $\Phi$ value by the $z$ value

Comment: Yes, the correct answer was 0.5899